# Why does my Horizontal List disappear with this code?

Tags: javascript, menu, hover

I got this code from [JavaScript Kit](http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/csstopmenu.shtml) and it's not working properly... Their site isn't very active so I posted here instead.  The list is displaying correctly, however, if I hover over the menu(main menu, submenus, etc) and then hover out, the entire menu disappears.  When you hover back over the main menu, it reappears.  The rest of the submenus appear correctly.  Any ideas?

JS:

```
    var cssmenuids=["navigation"] //Enter id(s) of CSS Horizontal UL menus, separated by commas
    var csssubmenuoffset=-1 //Offset of submenus from main menu. Default is 0 pixels.

    function createcssmenu2(){
    for (var i=0; i<cssmenuids.length; i++){
      var ultags=document.getElementById(cssmenuids[i]).getElementsByTagName("ul")
        for (var t=0; t<ultags.length; t++){
                            ultags[t].style.top=ultags[t].parentNode.offsetHeight+csssubmenuoffset+"px"
            var spanref=document.createElement("span")
                            spanref.className="arrowdiv"
                            spanref.innerHTML="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"
                            ultags[t].parentNode.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].appendChild(spanref)
            ultags[t].parentNode.onmouseover=function(){
                                            this.style.zIndex=100
            this.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].style.visibility="visible"
                                            this.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].style.zIndex=0
            }
            ultags[t].parentNode.onmouseout=function(){
                                            this.style.zIndex=0
                                            this.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].style.visibility="hidden"
                                            this.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].style.zIndex=100
            }
        }
      }
    }

    if (window.addEventListener)
    window.addEventListener("load", createcssmenu2, false)
    else if (window.attachEvent)
    window.attachEvent("onload", createcssmenu2)
```

HTML:

```
        <div id="navigation">

            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Forums</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Rosters</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Counter-Strike: Source</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Team Fortress 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Black Ops 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Complete Roster</a></li>
                    </ul></li>
                <li><a href="#">Matches</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Schedule</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Results</a></li>
                    </ul></li>
                <li><a href="#">Servers</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Recruiting</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>

    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#navigation {
    background: url(images/navigation_bg.gif) repeat-x;
    border-top: #666666;
    border-bottom: #333333;
    height: 59px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 59px;
}

#navigation ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    z-index: 100;
}

#navigation ul li {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}

#navigation ul li a {
    display: bock;
    width: 160px;
    padding: 2px 8px;
    border: 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: url(images/navigation_item_bg.gif) repeat-y left;
    color: #737373;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#navigation ul li.last a {
    display: bock;
    width: 160px;
    padding: 2px 8px;
    border: 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: url(images/navigation_item_bg.gif) repeat-y left, url(images/navigation_item_bg.gif) repeat-y right;
    color: #737373;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#navigation ul li ul {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #202020;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    visibility: hidden;
    zIndex: 100;
}

#navigation ul li ul li {
    display: inline;
    float: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#navigation ul li ul li a {
    width: 175px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #000;
    border-width: 0px 1px;
    padding: 0px 5px;
    display: block;
}

#navigation ul li ul li a:hover {
    background: #333333;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That script needs to exclude the topmost div and ul of the menu from hiding:

```js
if (this !== ultags[0].parentNode) {
    this.style.zIndex = 0;
    this.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].style.visibility = "hidden";
    this.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].style.zIndex = 100;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zkBun/)